# Google Cloud billed me 1000$

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was testing a cloud function and deployed it. I ran it but it seems like there were some excessive requests (not from my code's logic) that sent around more than a million requests back to the function I was testing. Then they billed me 1000$. What should I do? i am not living in the US so I cannot reach them by phone and there is no live chat support available.

Comment: Try to open a support-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a support case against the billing team, billing team will contact you in order yo clarify the month statement, if they made a mistake they can take actions.

You don't need a role based support.

***All Google Cloud accounts get free billing and payments support.***

**For Billing Administrators**

For Cloud Billing accounts you own, follow this link to contact Cloud Billing Support. Note that you must be a billing administrator on at least one Cloud Billing account to use this contact method.

[Contact Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing#for_billing_administrators)

If you receive an error message when you attempt to contact Cloud Billing Support, consider the following options:

-Sign into a billing administrator account or ask a billing administrator on the Cloud Billing account to contact support on your behalf.

-If you use Google Cloud through a reseller or other Google Partner, you must contact them for billing support.

**Alternative options to contact support**

If you are **not a billing administrator** on at least one Cloud Billing account, and you don't know how to contact your billing administrator, visit our contact troubleshooter to find an alternative contact option, depending on your issue.

[Support Contact Troubleshooter](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing#alternative_options_to_contact_support)

Comment: I tried contacting cloud billing support but all I get are bot responses with no additional help. Any way to contact a live agent?

Comment: I test it, when you open the link there is thenoption to chat with a agent. Try it